# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to execute a SQL stored procedure on my code below, the code commented out its working fine but I want to change how I get data using the stored procedure. Please kindly hint on the right direction.

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse> GetAllPackagesByOwner(string ownerStaffNumber)
{
    SqlParameter ownerStaffNumberParameter = new SqlParameter ("@ownerStaffNumber", ownerStaffNumber);

    var packages2 = await _context.PackageMaster.FromSqlRaw<PackageMaster>("EXECUTE dbo.spGetCurrentUserAssetList @ownerStaffNumber", ownerStaffNumberParameter)
        .ProjectTo<PackageMasterDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

I'm getting this error on package 2:

> 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: You cannot `SELECT` from a SP, try a function instead.

Comment: My SP contains a SELECT accepting a parameter

Comment: I don't think that's relevant.